# How can I close completely the file that I opened on visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm sorry that this question is not about coding problems but I could not find any information on the web. According to the title, I tried to remove the folder and file from explorer but I can't. Even if I closed vs code and reopened it, I can't close the folder and the folder stays in explorer on the side bar. Is there any solution or something ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVMwr.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to menu `File -> Close Folder` and click on it. It will close your project folder and all opened documents.